# Load Custom UIView in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I try to add my customView which is linked in my HomeViewcontroller in Interface Builder. Here one screenshot of the storyboard:
[image: IB]

All outlets are linked to CarouselView `IBOutlets`.

Here the UIView file (Carousel View in screenShot of Interface Builder) :

**CarouselScrollView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CarouselView: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentStatusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentCustomerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentAgencyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentPeriodLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nextAssignmentButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var previousAssignmentButton: UIButton!

init(frame: CGRect, _ status: String, _ customer: String, _ agency: String, _ period: String) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setupView("status", "customer", "agency", "period")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func setupView(_ status: String, _ customer: String, _ agency: String, _ period: String) {
    //        self.assignmentStatusLabel.text = status
    //        self.assignmentCustomerLabel.text = customer
    //        self.assignmentAgencyLabel.text = agency
    //        self.assignmentPeriodLabel.text = period
}}
```

Here my ViewController where I fill my scrollView with 3 CarouselView:

```
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: BaseViewController, HomeView {

@IBOutlet weak var carouselScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var carouselView: CarouselView!

var presenter: HomePresenter?
var currentAssignmentView: Int = 0
// create array of assignments for test
let arrayOfAssignments = [["status":"Mission en cours", "customer":"customer1", "agency":"bourg", "startDate":"09-05-2016", "endDate":"10-05-2016"],
                          ["status":"Mission à venir", "customer":"customer2", "agency":"agency paris", "startDate":"09-01-2017", "endDate":"03-04-2017"],
                          ["status":"Mission passée", "customer":"customer3", "agency":"agency lyon", "startDate":"09-09-2017", "endDate":"29-05-2018"]
]

override func initPresenter() -> BasePresenter {
    let presenter = HomePresenter(self, Navigator(self))
    self.presenter = presenter
    return presenter
}

override func setup() {
    self.navBarTitleImageSetup()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.scrollViewSetup()
}

func scrollViewSetup() {
    let carouselScrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.carouselScrollView.frame.width
    let carouselScrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.carouselScrollView.frame.height
    let numberOfAssignments = self.arrayOfAssignments.count

    self.carouselScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: carouselScrollViewWidth * CGFloat(numberOfAssignments), height: carouselScrollViewHeight)
    for i in 0...numberOfAssignments - 1 {
        let carouselView = CarouselView(frame: CGRect(x: carouselScrollViewWidth * CGFloat(i), y: CGFloat(0), width: carouselScrollViewWidth, height: carouselScrollViewHeight), "iuhiuh", "oiojoij", "iuhiuh", "iuhiuhiuh")
        switch i {
        case 0:
            carouselView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        case 1:
            carouselView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        case 2:
            carouselView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        default:
            break
        }
        self.carouselScrollView.addSubview(carouselView)
    }
    self.carouselScrollView.delegate = self
}

func navBarTitleImageSetup() {
    let image: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NavLogo")
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 97, height: 24))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}}

extension HomeViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let viewWidth: CGFloat = self.carouselScrollView.frame.width
    let currentAssignmentNumber: CGFloat = floor((self.carouselScrollView.contentOffset.x - viewWidth/2)/viewWidth)+1
    self.currentAssignmentView = Int(currentAssignmentNumber)
}}
```

When I Build & Run like that I can scroll my scroll view (3 views was added) but there is no label (normal because commented) :

[image: scroll1]
[image: scroll2]

But when I uncomment one of these lines in my CarouselScrollView.swift file :

```
    //        self.assignmentStatusLabel.text = status
    //        self.assignmentCustomerLabel.text = customer
    //        self.assignmentAgencyLabel.text = agency
    //        self.assignmentPeriodLabel.text = period
```

I have this error in console:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I don't understand why my label is `nil`. Everything seems ok. Someone has the solution or an idea?. In advance thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: Check if the labels are connected properly to outlets in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you but already done few times and the problem is not that.

Comment: Maybe you're using the labels before `awakeFromNib` is called.

Comment: Instead of creating the Custom-View inside Storyboard, try creating them in separate Nib file.

Comment: Paramasivan Samuttiram I did what you suggested but I was hoping there would be another solution in order to be able to keep the customView inside my Storyboard (to keep it just above my HomeController).

Then in CarouselView I added this :
class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "CarouselView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}

and in HomeViewController I instantiated my 3 custom views like that in my loop :
let carouselView = CarouselView.instanceFromNib() as! CarouselView

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The issue will get resolved if you call `setupView` after the `carouselView` is added as subview, because only after adding as subview your labels will be initialized.

Comment: How can I do that without make 2 loops instead of one ?

Than you user3057272

Comment: If you are talking about 'for' loop then you should create a property that tracks it maybe in 'setupView'

Answer (score 0):

Like said Paramasivan Samuttiram I had to create my customView in separate Nib(.xib) file. I was hoping there would be another solution in order to be able to keep the customView inside my Storyboard (to keep it just above my HomeController) but that did the trick.

In CarouselView I added this :

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView { return UINib(nibName: "CarouselView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView }
```

now CarouselView file looks like this:

```
class CarouselView: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentStatusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentCustomerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentAgencyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignmentPeriodLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nextAssignmentButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var previousAssignmentButton: UIButton!

class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "CarouselView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}}
```

And in HomeViewController I instantiated my 3 custom views like that in my loop in func scrollViewSetup:

```
func scrollViewSetup() {
    let carouselScrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.carouselScrollView.frame.width
    let carouselScrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.carouselScrollView.frame.height
    let numberOfAssignments = self.arrayOfAssignments.count

    self.carouselScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: carouselScrollViewWidth * CGFloat(numberOfAssignments), height: carouselScrollViewHeight)
    for i in 0...numberOfAssignments - 1 {
        let carouselView = CarouselView.instanceFromNib() as! CarouselView
        carouselView.frame = CGRect(x: carouselScrollViewWidth * CGFloat(i), y: CGFloat(0), width: carouselScrollViewWidth, height: carouselScrollViewHeight)
        carouselView.assignmentStatusLabel.text = self.arrayOfAssignments[i]["status"]
        carouselView.assignmentCustomerLabel.text = self.arrayOfAssignments[i]["customer"]?.uppercased()
        carouselView.assignmentAgencyLabel.text = self.arrayOfAssignments[i]["agency"]?.uppercased()
        carouselView.assignmentPeriodLabel.text = "\(self.arrayOfAssignments[i]["startDate"]!)  -  \(self.arrayOfAssignments[i]["endDate"]!)"
        self.carouselScrollView.addSubview(carouselView)
    }
    self.carouselScrollView.delegate = self
}
```

All work correctly now.

Thanks to all,